# How can I create a certain layout shape using css grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout of square divs something like this:

```
      xx
     xxxx
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
     xxxx
      xx
```

I'm not understanding css grid-template-area so well.
I tried:

```
html
<div class='container'>
 <div id="square"></div>
 <div id="square"></div>
 <div id="square"></div>
 <div id="square"></div>
 ...
</div>
```

```
css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "... ... square square ... ..."
  "... square square square square ..."
  "square square square square square square"
  "... square square square square ..."
  "... ... square square ... ..."
;

#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  grid-area: square;
}
}
```

If I could ask for pointers and help, thank you.
I can only see one square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made it like so for now (it looks dirty but it shows up fine):

```css
.grid {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 50px);
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". . two twoa . ."
    ". four foura fourb fourc ."
    "sixa sixb sixc sixd sixe sixf"
    "six2 six2a six2b six2c six2d six2e"
    ". four2 four2a four2b four2c ."
    ". . two2 two2a . ."
    ;
}

.hole {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url('../images/dirt.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
}

.two-hole {
    grid-area: two;
}
.two-holeA {
    grid-area: twoa;
}
.two-hole2 {
    grid-area: two2;
}
.two-hole2A {
    grid-area: two2a;
}

.four-hole {
    grid-area: four;
}
.four-holeA {
    grid-area: foura;
}
.four-holeB {
    grid-area: fourb;
}
.four-holeC {
    grid-area: fourc;
}

.four-hole2 {
    grid-area: four2;
}
.four-hole2A {
    grid-area: four2a;
}
.four-hole2B {
    grid-area: four2b;
}
.four-hole2C {
    grid-area: four2c;
}

.six-holeA {
    grid-area: sixa;
}
.six-holeB {
    grid-area: sixb;
}
.six-holeC {
    grid-area: sixc;
}
.six-holeD {
    grid-area: sixd;
}
.six-holeE {
    grid-area: sixe;
}
.six-holeF {
    grid-area: sixf;
}

.six-hole2 {
    grid-area: six2;
}
.six-hole2A {
    grid-area: six2a;
}
.six-hole2B {
    grid-area: six2b;
}
.six-hole2C {
    grid-area: six2c;
}
.six-hole2D {
    grid-area: six2d;
}
.six-hole2E {
    grid-area: six2e;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
            <div class="hole two-hole" id="1">1</div>
            <div class="hole two-holeA" id="2">2</div>
            <div class="hole four-hole" id="3">3</div>
            <div class="hole four-holeA" id="4">4</div>
            <div class="hole four-holeB" id="5">5</div>
            <div class="hole four-holeC" id="6">6</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeA" id="7">7</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeB" id="8">8</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeC" id="9">9</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeD" id="10">0</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeE" id="11">11</div>
            <div class="hole six-holeF" id="12">12</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2" id="13">13</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2A" id="14">14</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2B" id="15">15</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2C" id="16">16</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2D" id="17">17</div>
            <div class="hole six-hole2E" id="18">18</div>
            <div class="hole four-hole2" id="19">19</div>
            <div class="hole four-hole2A" id="20">2</div>
            <div class="hole four-hole2B" id="21">22</div>
            <div class="hole four-hole2C" id="22">23</div>
            <div class="hole two-hole2" id="23">24</div>
            <div class="hole two-hole2A" id="24">25</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you can't use the same id for more than one element. Second, you can achieve this using flexbox by centering and resizing the children as desired without any CSS grid as following

```css
#container{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    }
.rhombus{
background:red;
width:90vw;
height: 13vh;
margin: 1vh;
}
#first-row{
width:30vw
}
#second-row{
width:60vw
}
#third-row{
width:90vw
}
#fourth-row{
width:90vw
}
#fifth-row{
width:60vw
}
#sixth-row{
width:30vw
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="rhombus" id="first-row"></div>
<div class="rhombus" id="second-row"></div>
<div class="rhombus" id="third-row"></div>
<div class="rhombus" id="fourth-row"></div>
<div class="rhombus" id="fifth-row"></div>
<div class="rhombus" id="sixth-row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, maybe I didn't ask in detail. I need each individual box (24 of them).

Comment: You can make each row flexbox and nest as many items as you need in each row